# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - Express + Request

Tags: node.js, express

I understand this is a very basic question to ask but I find myself spending too much time to understand why this happen.

Below is the api in which I use npm request lib to query the api and I send the response with express response. When i hit this, I get:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\GayathriGanesan\Documents\sampleNode\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\GayathriGanesan\Documents\sampleNode\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\GayathriGanesan\Documents\sampleNode\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\GayathriGanesan\Documents\sampleNode\app.js:80:34)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\GayathriGanesan\Documents\sampleNode\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\GayathriGanesan\Documents\sampleNode\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\GayathriGanesan\Documents\sampleNode\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
```

Below is the code which was written.

```
     var express = require('express');
     var app = express();
     var request=require("request");
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
     app.use(function(req, res, next) {
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,    Content-Type, Accept,clientSecret");
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS');

            next();
      });

      app.post("/push/v1/apps/:appID/devices",function(req,response){
                var appID=req.params.appID;
            var options={
                url:"https://pushapp.sampleapp.net/push/v1/apps/"+appID+"/devices",
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':req.headers["content-type"],
                    'clientSecret':req.headers["clientsecret"]
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(req.body)
            }
               request.post(options,function(err,res,body){
                if(res.statusCode==201){  
                    response.sendStatus(201).json(JSON.parse(body));
                }
                else{
                    response.sendStatus(res.statusCode);
                }

            });

            });
```

Could you please help understand why. I could somehow guess callback is happening twice. But not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `res.sendStatus` sets the given response HTTP status code and sends its string representation as the response body (see [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendStatus)). `res.json` will set the content-type response header, but at time time the response will already have been sent to the client.

So instead of using `res.sendStatus` you could simply use `res.status`:

```
response.status(201).json(JSON.parse(body));
```

Comment: but i came across fact that status is deprecated.

Comment: Does not seem to be the case: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3d10279826f59bf68e28995ce423f7bc4d2f11cf/lib/response.js#L66
Where did you read that?

Comment: hey..am sorry. i guess i got confused with res.send(Status) . Thanks for your inputs. it indeed helped me much. Thankyou!

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to accept the answer ;)